# How is a Java object constructed?

Tags: java, language-implementation

If I create a class like:

```
public class Test{
       int id;
       String name;
}
```

Now, if I have to use the class, we have to just create a instance of the class as

```
Test testObj = new Test();
```

I would like to know how the actual object is created in the system. (In core level, what will be the structure of the object.)

Comment: Remember that case matters, so your code won't compile because test is not the same as Test.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "core level"? How the VM organizes its memory? And why do you want to know? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DaveJohnston yep, but the question is still vague without this problem. Updated.

Comment: Why is people rating down this question? The guy wants to know how a VM stores objects in memory, what's wrong with that? May be it's unimportant to most of us but that's no reason to down vote this

Comment: why all the down votes? the guy wants to undestand classes/objects, but can't express it well (well he's learning that's why) ...

Comment: You can say it as machine level processing and management.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the actual virtual machine (vendor, version). There's no detailed specification on *how* a VM should store the instance.

> [The Java virtual machine does not mandate any particular internal structure for objects.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#16066)